# Switch google adsense ad (mobile vs regular) based on user agent

Tags: javascript, adsense, user-agent

I'm optimizing a site so that on a mobile browser it only shows the mobile adsense ad, and on desktop it only shows the regular one. Problem is the google code leaves a white space where these ads are on the page.

I want to know if there is an easy way to programmatically insert the ad (JS) based on the user agent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, see [Masquerading Your Browser](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/masquerading-your-browser.html) for details on how the User-Agent header works. See also the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

You haven't said which server side language you're using. In PHP you would look at the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.